# Swing only draws one of two JPanels?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I'm building a display API in Java for an internship. Loading in a single image works, but as soon as i want to add another the first image disappears and only draws the second one. Any ideas on how to fix this?

The main class:

```
package com.lespaul.display;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

public class Window extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3716315131567381715L;

    public Window() {
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setSize(200, 200);
        this.setVisible(true);
        Image pane = new Image("floor.png");
        Image pane2 = new Image("floor.png");
        this.add(pane);
        this.add(pane2);
        pane2.setPosition(50,50);
        this.revalidate();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Window window = new Window();
    }
}
```

And this is the actual image...

```
package com.lespaul.display;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

import com.lespaul.position.*;

public class Image extends JPanel {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -5815516814733234713L;
    public BufferedImage image;
    public Vector2 position = new Vector2(0, 0);

    public Image() {

    }
    public Image(String ref){
        try {
            this.addImage(ref);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    public void setPosition(int x, int y){
        Dimension size = this.getPreferredSize();
        Insets insets = this.getInsets();
        this.setBounds(x+insets.left,y+insets.top,size.width,size.height);
        this.position.x = x;
        this.position.y = y;
        repaint();
    }
    public void addImage(String fileName) throws IOException {
        URL url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource(fileName);
        image = ImageIO.read(url);

    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (image != null)
            g.drawImage(image,(int)position.x,(int)position.y, null);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example). 2) One way to get image(s) for an example is to hot-link to the images seen in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19209651/418556).

Comment: *"I need it to be in an absolute position"*  Absolutely where?  Java GUIs might have to work on a number of platforms, on different screen resolutions & using different PLAFs.  As such they are not conducive to exact placement of components.  To organize the components for a robust GUI, instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556), along with layout padding & borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17874717/418556).

Answer (score 2):

Don't call your class Image. There is a Java Interface by that name which makes your code confusing.

If you want to paint multiple images at different locations then the common solution is to keep track of the Images in an ArrayList and then create a custom component that loops through the ArrayList to paint the images at the specified location.

Check out [Custom Painting Approaches](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for an example. The `DrawOnComponent` example will give you an idea of how to implement this approach.

Comment: @AndrewThompson, Sometimes the fingers just don't type what the brain I thinking :)

Comment: At least the brain *is* thinking.  With lots of things I read, I wonder if that was the case with the author.. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use any layout like

```
    jFrame.getContentPane().add(jPanel1,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    jFrame.getContentPane().add(jPanel2,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

Comment: Still does not work. That just puts the image somewhere at the top. I need it to be in an absolute position

Answer (score -1):

The best practice is use [layouts](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) to manage components locations.

Good luck!

Comment: The problem is that I need to do this sort of stuff absolute, not with layouts...

Comment: This answer should have been a comment, and the comment is bad advice and should be deleted.